# How to document API (REST/SOAP) client and consumers

Tags: api, rest, soap

I need to document our REST API and have the possibility to do impact analysis : for example I need to know that an API call depend on another API in order to prevent cycle ... I also need to know what impact there is in updating a shared structure ...
  I have already generated a swagger documentation for my REST Apis for example : but this is not covering all my needs... 
 Are there any tools or method in order to cover my needs ?